# I am adding rows to table by javascript but when I submit the page, C# doesnt see added rows

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, dynamically-generated

I am adding rows to a table in my ASPX page using JavaScript and it works fine, but when I submit the page, c# doesn't see newly added rows but only ones hardcoded in ASPX page.

ASPX

```
<table id="frmTable" runat="server">
  <tr>
     <td colspan="2">
        <input type="button" title="Text" onclick="AddToForm('Text')" value="Text" />
        <input type="submit" ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnServerClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
     </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

JavaScript function

```
    function AddToForm(type) {
        var tbl = document.getElementById("frmTable");
        var row = tbl.insertRow();
        var cell = row.insertCell();
        cell.setAttribute("datatype", 'text');
        cell.setAttribute('isrequired', 'no');
        var field = document.createElement("input");
        cell.appendChild(field);
```

}

C# code behind

`protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write(frmTable.Rows[0].Cells[0].Attributes["datatype"] + " --
 " + frmTable.Rows[0].Cells[0].Attributes["isrequired"]);
    }`

When I check row count in btnSubmit_Click event, frmTable only sees 1 row that has submit button, but doesn't see the row that has been successfully added by Javascript.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET does not post back the entire page, but only relevant parts. Please check on ASP.NET View State, it's crucial and pretty much to digest.

Comment: Either that or make your own custom handler and post only the data you need.

Comment: Hi Mihai 

So, if I want to add rows to table via Javascript, to avoid extra trips to the server every time I create new row and its cells with controls and then have them visible to the server code what should be my approach?

Comment: You can use Ajax for posting each row at a time without submitting the page, or just create a hidden input control server side and modify it with JavaScript. The modification will be visible server side since you'll be using the server side HiddenField control.